# reloadData() doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have looked at tutorials everywhere and not a single one has helped me.... reloadData does absolutely nothing

```
import UIKit

class searchView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    var user: User!
    var updatedSearch: String = ""
    var keys: [String]!
    var dict: [String: [String]]!
    var tableArray: [String] = ["15", "14", "13", "12", "11", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
    let size = 15

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Section: \(section)")
        return tableArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableArray[indexPath.row]
        print("Cell: \(cell.textLabel!.text!)")
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }

    func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        print("Text Changed")
        updateTable()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UITextField!

    @IBAction func doneNavButton(sender: UIButton) {
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    func readCityDocument() -> NSDictionary{
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cities", ofType: "txt")
        do{
            let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            return getDictionary(content)
        }
        catch{
            print("error")
        }
        return NSDictionary()
    }

    func getDictionary(doc: String) -> NSDictionary{
        print("Parsing Document....")
        let document = doc.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        var doc2: [[String]] = []
        var dict: [String: [String]] = NSDictionary() as! [String : [String]]
        for x in document{
            doc2.append(x.componentsSeparatedByString(","))
        }
        for y in doc2{
            dict[y[0]] = y
        }
        print("Done....")
        return dict
    }

    func updateTable(){
        var siz = size
        var newTableArray = [String]()
        for x in keys{
            if x.hasPrefix(searchBar.text!){
                let val: String!
                if (dict[x]!.count == 4){
                    let ar = dict[x]
                    val = "\(ar![0]), \(ar![2]), \(ar![3])"
                }
                else{
                    let ar = dict[x]
                    val = "\(ar![0]), \(ar![1]), \(ar![2])"
                }
                newTableArray.append(val)
                siz = siz - 1
                if (siz == 0){
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableArray = newTableArray
        print("reload the damn Data...")
        self.table.reloadData()

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var x = size
        while (x > 0){
            tableArray.append("\(x)")
            x = x - 1
        }
        print(tableArray.description)
        self.table.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        print("Creating Dictionary from City Document...")
        dict = readCityDocument() as! [String : [String]]
        keys = []
        for (key, _) in dict{
            keys.append(key)
        }
        searchBar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchView.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        print("Memory Warning?")
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this on viewDidLoad

`self.table.delegate = self
self.table.dataSource = self`

Comment: Ok this solved all my problems even though i had already done this from the main story board lol... I ended up deleting the table and putting a new one in and it worked. I must have messed with the settings on the old table and cause it to have issues in the code. Thanks though haha!